# how to end (complete) an async* stream created based on another infinite stream?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I have an **await for** loop getting data from an infinite stream inside an **stream  function async*** function
I would like to complete (end) the stream on certain condition.

I was expecting `break;` out of the `await for` will do it but it does not.
any suggestions?
here is a code snippet:

```
Stream<int> conditionLoop() async* {     
  await for (double value in hardware.inputStream()) {
      if (value < 0.0 || value > 98.0) break;
    yield value.round();
  }
  print('stream completed!');
}
```

The **print('stream completed!')** command never happened and the StreamBuilder widget never gets "ConnectionState.done"

Thanks.

Comment: `break` indeed does leave the `await for`. If your function doesn't work, then your `break` is not reached.

Comment: Remove for loop and try using .then after input stream method and use if condition in it. and stop that stream using stream subscription.